# Using (_ <- f) instead of f Alone?

Tags: haskell, do-notation

Looking at this ZeroMQ [HelloWorldClient.hs](http://zguide.zeromq.org/hs:hwclient) code snippet:

```
forM_ [1..10] $ \i -> do
    liftIO . putStrLn $ "Sending Hello " ++ show i ++ "…"
    send requester [] "Hello"
    _ <- receive requester
    liftIO . putStrLn $ "Received World " ++ show i
```

Is there any reason why `_ <- receive requester` wouldn't be written as `receive requester`?

Also, in general, is there any reason to use `_ <- f` (where `f : Monad m => m a`) instead of `f`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a common way to silence warnings about throwing away a value, when you've got something of type `m a` where `a` is not `()`. Another common way to do this is with `void`.

Comment: Could you please explain how void would be used per your mention of it?

Comment: @KevinMeredith `void (receive requester)` or more conveniently `void $ receive requester`